# javascript new date() returns invalid date in Unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

date object returns invalid date in Unit test. 
Failing test in test explorer but passing in browser.

```js
date = function () {
    return function (value) {
        if (value != undefined) {
            var dateString = value.toString();
            if (dateString.length > 0) {
                var d = new Date(dateString);
                return (d.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "/" + d.getDate().toString() + "/" + d.getFullYear().toString();
            }
        }
            return "";
        }
    };
```

Comment: What invalid date is it returning?

Comment: what result do you expect ?

Comment: What is `value` when it fails? Also, click on "Run code snippet"; note how noting happens. Please [edit] your question to show how you are calling this function, in a [mcve].

Comment: You may also be interested in [Converting string to date in js](//stackoverflow.com/q/5619202)

Comment: You can try something like `isNaN(Date.parse(dateString)) return ''` to validate the datestring first.

Comment: value is "1" @Mike McCaughan